# textbox that is insde the combobox as comboboxitems in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox in WPF. I put the `TextBox` in it as `ComboBoxItem`. Now I want the `ComboBoxItem` to be filtered when I type in `TextBox`:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="23,8,22,29" Name="comboBox1" DropDownOpened="comboBox1_DropDownOpened">
  <ComboBoxItem>
    <TextBox Name="texcombo" Width="90" Foreground="Gray"  GotFocus="texcombo_GotFocus" KeyDown="texcombo_KeyDown" TextChanged="texcombo_TextChanged"  >جستجو</TextBox>
  </ComboBoxItem>                  
  <ComboBoxItem>سلام</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>خوبی</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>عرض ادب</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>سپاسگذارم</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>مرسی</ComboBoxItem>                   
</ComboBox>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

the way you are implementing the Textbox inside ComboBox is wrong. First of all, you should change the Combobox default template to show a specific Textbox inside it instead of putting the Textbox inside items. Then you should bind an observable collection (for data) to ComboBox items. Now you can filter the ObservableCollection based on TextBox TextChanged event or command.

Comment: But I want my data to be fixed. And that I could show the textbox the same way

Comment: i can show own wpf form to you. that involve textbox  inside cobobox